# pass data from view to controller without refreshing the view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, .post

i have a script in my view which is:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker
(
{ onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
    //pass dateText to my controller

});
 </script>
```

my controller is like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string dateSelected = dateText; //read dateText here
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateSelected, out date))
        {
            date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateSelected);
            var reservations = db.Reservations.Where(r => r.Date == date).Include(r => r.Employee).Include(r => r.Room).OrderByDescending(r => r.Date);

            return View(reservations);
        }
        return View();

    }
```

i want dateText to be passed to the controller without the current page being refreshed or reloaded. how to do that?

i tried forms earlier and on the onselect event of the datepicker, i automatically submit the form so the controller can accept it. but i do not want the current page to be refreshed or reloaded.

i just want to pass dateText to the controller without the user noticing the passing.. some sort of $.post i guess but i dont know how to implement it..

UPDATE: here is my try, what is wrong:

ok here is my script:

```
     JSONstring = JSON.stringify(dateText);
    $.post("/Home/Index", { jsonData: JSONstring });
```

here is my controller:

```
     public ActionResult Index(string jsonData)
    {
        CacheClear();
        string dateSelected = jsonData;
         .....
        //i tried to debug it, but no value of jsonData

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ajax and send all the variables or data in the ajax data string and provide the url of your controller for example

```
    function add_to_cart(id , title, price,qty){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
   url: "your controller" + id ,
  data: "&title=" + title + "&price=" + price +"&quantity=" + qty ,
        complete: function(data) {
            //alert("Item added to cart");

        }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

> i want dateText to be passed to the controller without the current
>   page being refreshed or reloaded. how to do that?

You could use AJAX.

Comment: been trying to do that but i dont understand it fully, im just a beginner... so i am trying .post

Comment: @eaon21 then show us what you have tried and maybe we can help with that issue.

Comment: ok here is my script:

 JSONstring = JSON.stringify(dateText);
        $.post("/Home/Index", { jsonData: JSONstring });

here is my controller: 
 public ActionResult Index(string jsonData)
        {
            CacheClear();
            string dateSelected = jsonData;
.....
            //i tried to debug it, but no value of jsonData
        
        }

Comment: Did you verify that the `JSONstring` variable contains some value on the client before sending the AJAX request?